# Relative path in ejs file

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to create an express app and it has the following folder structure.

```
--My_App
   --public
      --stylesheets
         app.css
   --views
      --camps
         index.ejs
      --partials
         header.ejs
   app.js
```

I have set the `express` to serve the static files of public directory as well `app.use(express.static("public"));`

Here's the problem:

I link the `app.css` file to my `index.ejs` file, using `href` attribute of `<link>` tag,
by using the path = `"/stylesheets/app.css"`, and it works.

But when I try to link the `header.ejs` file to `index.ejs` file using 
`<% include /partials/header.ejs %>` 
it gives an error -  `could not find "/partials/header.ejs"` . Shouldn't this work since express serves the contents of views directory as well

Also, Can you please mention the corresponding absolute paths of above relative paths used.

Comment: have you tried try "../partials/header.ejs"

Comment: Yes, it works. But I want to know why it doesn't work with `<% include /partials/header.ejs%>`

Comment: ".ejs" is not static files but gets processed in the v8 engine.Further more you are including one file in another.That is different from having a link to the file in another.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the reply. I have one more query (sorry for inconvenience). Do both the relative paths point to the same root directory?

Comment: i think you need to understand what  these lines of code mean in your code if you have them app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

Comment: ejs files are relative to the views folder and any other static file is relative to the public folder

Comment: static files are served to the browser(client) just the way they are but the ejs files are processed by  the view engine within the server(ejs) and an html file is generated then served to the server

Comment: I hope all is clear

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in the path.

```
    var path = require('path');
    express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

And you should give the correct path

```
<% include ./views/partials/header.ejs%>
```

Answer (score 0):

app.js

```
app.use( '/data', express.static('data') )
```

index.ejs

```
<%- include ( `../views/partials/header.ejs` ) -%>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.